# Action listener for all checkboxes in a scroll pane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events

I am working in Java swings. I have two scrollpanes contain n1 and n2 number of checkboxes. If a checkbox in first scrollpane is selected then i have to disable a corresponding checkbox in second scrollpane and vice versa. Do i need to add actionlistener on all the checkboxes? If i have say 20 checkboxes, adding 20 action listeners seems a bit of work. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i need to add actionlistener on all the checkboxes?

Yes, if you wish to be able to respond to events triggered by that Component.

> Is there a better way to do it?

If you have several Components, consider using an array to allow you to loop over the components. You can implement many `ActionListener`'s - one for each Component - or use a single `ActionListener`. If the latter, you can check the Component that fired the event by checking the source of the event.

```
final int totalNumber = 20;
final JCheckBox[] boxes = new JCheckBox[totalNumber ];
ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
        for ( int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++ ){
            if ( c == boxes[i] ){//this is the component that fired the event
                //do something
            }
        }
    } 
};
for ( int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++ ){
    boxes[i] = new JCheckBox("Box " + i);
    boxes[i].addActionListener(myListener);
    parentContainer.add(boxes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the listener to each of the checkboxes. However you can write a simple method that loops through all the components of the scroll pane, filtering those that are checkboxes, and binding the listener to each of them. This lets you avoid manually binding the listener to each checkbox.